# Custom svg icon not centered like Official Material Design icon

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am trying to center a custom svg icon but I cannot do it although the same css works for an Official Material Design icon (I added an aqua background so it will be easier to see where the frame is).

On the far left it's the custom svg I added, and next to it, on the right, it's the Official one:
[image]

My css:

```
div.container {
    max-width: 512px;
    min-width: 256px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #9e9e9e;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 30px;
  }

div.img {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #9e9e9e;
    background-color: #3f9c35;
}

div.img mat-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

my html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="information">info</mat-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
  </div>
  Some text here!
</div>
```

Please find the code in [this repo](https://github.com/mmm2306/mat-icon-issue).

Any suggestions on how to center the custom svg icon like the official Material design one?

Also, if you could suggest a platform where I could connect it to the repo and anyone can run it so it will be easier for sharing the code and running it at the same time. Most platforms won't let me upload assets.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet? It would be easier to read and to provide an answer

Comment: added code snippet